# What is \u0026#39;n and how do I decode it?

Tags: php, encoding

So I have a string that is in another language,  most of it looks great,  but parts of it is encoded incorrectly.  How do I convert the literal string `\u0026#39;n` into its unicode(?) equivalent in PHP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following PHP function will translate `\u0026#39;n` into `'n`.  This is used to communicate with the Google Translate API.

```
function unescapeUTF8EscapeSeq($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback("/\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i",
        create_function('$matches',
            'return html_entity_decode(\'&#x\'.$matches[1].\';\', ENT_QUOTES, \'UTF-8\');'
        ), $str);
}
```

Comment: with this code you will be able to convert all ascii codes to single characters.

Comment: I can't edit, but the code should be updated to remove create_function which is now deprecated; replace create_function with -- function($matches) { return html_entity_decode('&#x'.$matches[1].';', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); },

Answer (score 6):

To update @rook's answer to use an inline callback rather than the depriated `create_function` method you get:

```
                    function unescapeUTF8EscapeSeq($str)
                    {
                        return preg_replace_callback(
                            "/\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i",
                            function ($matches) {
                                return html_entity_decode('&#x' . $matches[1] . ';', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                            },
                            $str
                        );
                    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Picking it apart, that looks to have been through at least two different encoding processes. To start with `\u0026` - that's unicode code point hex `26`, or 38 in decimal. The first 128 unicode codepoints are the same as ASCII, so this is ASCII 38, an ampersand.

So now we have `&#39;n`, which looks like an HTML or XML entitization for character 39, which is the single quote character, `'`.

Giving us `'n`. Which I can't see how to decode further - does the context provide further clues?

Comment: Character entities are not in hex unless they use the letter `x`.
`&#39;` is the single quote character, `'`, not the digit 9.  The digit 9 is `&#x39;` or `&#57;`.